# Automative way to check mysql grants

Tags: mysql, sql

we have many users in our mysql server with alot of grants. Is there exists some automated way to check that all grants are really required for these users base on query set which these users use?

For example:
you have user1 and user2 and known that user1 do query1, query2, query3. user2 do others query4, query5, query6. Could I predict in automatic way, which grants are required for these users,  base on these queries, to compare these autogenerated grants set with grants which already exists in our db server to remove excesive grants?

Comment: It is not clear what is required for your question? It sounds too broad. Could you share some code and make the question a bit more specific?

Comment: No. None way may predict what permissions are needed for a user.